# PostgreSQL: Hard max_wal_size or replication slot timeout

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

is it possible to configure something like a timeout for inactive (logical) replication slots or a hard max_wal_size, which is applied even if there is an inactive replication slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before v13 there is no such thing, and you have to use `wal_keep_segments` instead of replication slots.

From v13 on, you can set a limit with `max_slot_wal_keep_size`. If that is exceeded, the primary will remove WAL segments even if a replication slot says that someone still needs them. That will of course break replication for the standby that uses this slot.

Comment: You are probably right. I think the new [temporary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/protocol-replication.html#PROTOCOL-REPLICATION-CREATE-SLOT) property for replication slots might be another option to get rid of inactive replication slots, although a timeout option would have been nice to give the client a chance to reconnect.

Comment: Temporary things go away when the connection does. That wouldn't be useful in your case, would it?

Comment: It would be ok in my case. My application could take a database snapshot when it reconnects and after that continue to read logs. But should not happen too often.

Comment: In PostgreSQL v13 you have: `max_slot_wal_keep_size`, "Specify the maximum size of WAL files that replication slots are allowed to retain in the pg_wal directory at checkpoint time."

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Thanks, I have adapted the answer.